react-query: Types of property 'isSuccess' are incompatible
i have a code like this:
import { get } from "lodash-es"
import {useQuery} from '@tanstack/react-query'

type QueryResult<TData extends object> =
    | {
          isSuccess: false
          isPending: true
          isError: false
          data: undefined
      }
    | {
          isSuccess: true
          isPending: false
          isError: false
          data: TData
      }

class DataListManager<TData extends object, TPath extends keyof TData> {
    constructor(
        private readonly _query: QueryResult<TData>,
        private readonly _path: TPath,
    ) {}

    get query() {
        const items = get(this._query.data, this._path) ?? []

        return {
            ...this._query,
            data: {
                items,
            },
        }
    }
}

type Transaction = {}

function useTransactionsListManager() {
    const query = useQuery({
        async queryFn() {
            const data = await new Promise<{transactions: Array<Transaction>}>(resolve => {
                resolve({
                    transactions: []
                })
            })

            return data
        },
        queryKey: ['transactions']
    })

    //  Argument of type 'UseQueryResult<{ transactions: Transaction[]; }, Error>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryResult<{ transactions: Transaction[]; }>'.
    //   Type 'QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult<{ transactions: Transaction[]; }, Error>' is not assignable to type 'QueryResult<{ transactions: Transaction[]; }>'.
    //     Type 'QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult<{ transactions: Transaction[]; }, Error>' is not assignable to type '{ isSuccess: true; isPending: false; isError: false; data: { transactions: Transaction[]; }; }'.
    //       Types of property 'isSuccess' are incompatible.
    //         Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2345)
    return new DataListManager(query, "transactions")
}

Why I getting this error and how can I fix it?
Update
I can't use UseQueryResult inside DataListManager due to architectural restrictions.
Playground

If the "architectural reasons" are "I don't want to couple DataListManager to @tanstack/react-query" then that's bogus. You are still coupled, but you've made it harder to see the coupling

You don't need to define your own QueryResult type, you can import it from @tanstack/react-query
import {useQuery, UseQueryResult} from '@tanstack/react-query'

class DataListManager<TData extends object, TPath extends keyof TData> {
    constructor(
        private readonly _query: UseQueryResult<TData>,
        private readonly _path: TPath,
    ) {}

    get query() {
        const items = get(this._query.data, this._path) ?? []

        return {
            ...this._query,
            data: {
                items,
            },
        }
    }
}

If you need to refine it, use Pick
type QueryResult<TData extends object> = Pick<UseQueryResult<TData>, "isSuccess" | "isPending" | "isError" | "data">

Playground

I can't do that, I need to minimally repeat the UseQueryResult<TData type

@PavelPerevezencev you don't need to repeat it to minimise it's members

Why do you think so?

@PavelPerevezencev See the edit. Pick<UseQueryResult<TData>, "isSuccess" | "isPending" | "isError" | "data"> is a type that has the same members as your attempt

Yes, but it also uses UseQueryResult

@PavelPerevezencev Yes. You should use UseQueryResult. That is what it is for. Your question doesn't mention any artificial restrictions
